# Is there any python equivalent of OOBPermutedVarDeltaError from Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

OOBPermutedVarDeltaError states that

> For any variable, the measure is the increase in prediction error if the values of that variable are permuted across the observations. This measure is computed for every tree, then averaged over the entire ensemble and divided by the standard deviation over the entire ensemble

To find its equivalent would I need to calculate the increase in prediction error across observations and then average it across the entire ensemble? Being fairly new to ML, I am not sure how I would implement it even. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, there arent any. Python and Matlab, does not scale 1:1